# How can i generate variadic macro for concatenate string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

I got stuck here...

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT(a,b))
#define CONCAT1(a,b,c) CONCAT(CONCAT(a,b),c) and so on.
```

How i can to generate the CONCAT macro even if 20 arguments?  May be i can to use **BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH** but i don't understand how to do it?

Comment: What are the arguments to this macro. Can you give example ? Remember that string concatenation can be done by compiler itself and without any use of macro, if they are string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on you use-case.

This

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define SEQ (a)(b)(c)

BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT(SEQ)) // "abc"
```

will concatenate the sequence and then stringize it. It is also possible to simply stringize each argument as `"a" "b" "c"` is equivalent to `"abc"`.

```
#define MY_STRINGIZE(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem)
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MY_STRINGIZE, _, SEQ)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using the Boost libraries, try `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT` ([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_cat.html)). It takes a list of elements and simply concatenates them together, i.e. `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT(a b c)`
results in `abc`.